# Python PyQt5 Add Remote Debugging To Compiled Application

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, remote-debugging

In my project I create an application which I then compile with pyinstaller.

The application allows the end-user to add HTML5 files into a folder which the python script then runs as a web app using PyQt5.

During develpment debugging said web app is done by runing the script with the command-line argument `--remote-debugging-port=8080` which gives access to the developer tools as a local web page using a Chromium based browser.

However once the application is compiled with pyinstaller these developer tools are no longer available for the end-user. I was trying to use `argparse` to fix this but it did not work:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=8080")
    parser.parse_args()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, how can I add remote debugging to my compiled program?

Comment: The value of [`add_argument()`](//docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) is the argument name, not it's complete syntax, otherwise the *actual* value of the argument couldn't be specified: it should be something like `add_argument('--remote-debugging-port')`; use the `default` keyword for the default value. I suggest you to study the documentation and the official [tutorial](//docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) using simple test programs that you could eventually build with pyinstaller so that you can actually test the argument from the command line.